# formatting with variadic variables

Tags: c, variadic

c89
gcc 4.7.4

I was just experimenting with macros like these:

```
#define LOG_INFO_1(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO_2(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

And using like this:

```
LOG_INFO_1("%s:%d", __func__, __LINE__);
LOG_INFO_2("%s:%d", __func__, __LINE__);
```

The output gives exactly the same format. I am just wondering what is the advantage of having the `fmt` argument in my first macro? It doesn't seem to be really needed. How could I make use of it?

Comment: There is a difference if you only want to pass the format string, e.g. `LOG_INFO_1("just a simple string")`.  When you do that, `LOG_INFO_1` will result in a compiler error, due to the trailing comma in the call to `printf` (since `__VA_ARGS__` expands to the empty string in that case), whereas `LOG_INFO_2` will expand correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying that the first parameter is `fmt` makes no difference to the compiler/computer.

However, I think it makes a big difference to other programmers who may use your code.

Looking at `LOG_INFO_1(fmt, ...)`, I see a strong hint that this macro takes a printf-style format string with additional parameters after.

Looking at `LOG_INFO_2(...)`, I have no idea what parameters should be passed, or in what order.  Maybe the first parameter should be a [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) severity code?  Maybe it should be an output stream to write to?   Nothing in the macro hints at the answer.

I think you should make work easier for the programmers who come after you by specifying as much as possible, and only leaving ambiguities such as `...` only where absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For macros it does not matter which variation you use. The preprocessor will produce the same C code from both macros.

---

For variadic functions at least one argument needs to be defined.

So

```
void foo(const char * fmt, ...);
```

would compile, whereas

```
void bar(...);
```

wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ACE_DEBUG/Log_Msg](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/ACE-5.5.2/html/ace/Log__Msg_8h-source.html). ACE (adaptive communications environment) is an established c++ framework for networking. They've implemented a thread-safe logging architecture using macros and variadic variables in a similar way.